# Can I use logs instead comments in my code?

Tags: logging

Is anybody using logs instead of comments? Is it right?

For example:

```
logger.debug('Fingerprint is not specified. Returning only message that password is correct in response.');
logger.info('Password is correct. But fingerprintId was not passed. User ID:', foundUser.id);
logger.debug('Returning success message in response.');
```

Logging in this case does 2 things: logging and commenting.

Is it common practice?

Comment: That should probably be tagged _python_ as well

Comment: I think it is common question. For example I am coding server with js and android app in java.

Comment: your example code looks like Python, but it's OK if your question could be applied to any language. BTW, what kind of comments are you talking about? Those in the source code?

Comment: Yes! Comments in source code

Comment: I think this question was not well addressed. It deserves more attention. I really do believe that logging well allows fewer comments!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that comments and logging just serve for different purposes.

Logging is done *to see what your program is doing right now or what it was doing at a specific point*. For example, you open a log file and check what was going on five minutes ago and what's happening now. That's useful when you don't really bother *at which line or in which method exactly* is something happening, you're more interested in facts, like *'User admin failed to login: incorrect password'*. Obviously, that helps a lot when you don't have source code of the program.

Comments help you to understand *what this code does*, what this particular function is doing, why this variable is here and *how is all this supposed to work*. But if you've got just a binary, comments are totally useless.

To my mind, you simply can't mess it all together since comments and logging are different.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is room for debate.
Some comments can be replaced with logs, some cannot.

If we can increase the readability of the code while reducing redundant lines that is an excellent thing to do. Instead of having a comment and a log we can potentially combine them into one.

One example that might work well is replacing TODOs with warnings as shown below. In my humble experience, TODOs often fall by the wayside and I forget about them.

https://medium.com/practical-software-testing/replace-todo-comments-in-your-code-with-warning-log-messages-maybe-7e8b5534225c

Ultimately is should come down to answering these questions:
Is it safe to do this, are exposing too much code by logging it?
Is it practical?
Does it improve code readability?
Does it reduce redundancy in our work load or add too it?
Does it create excessive logging?

If we intend to use logging to replace PART, not ALL of our comments care must be taken to not overload the log.

Here is the paradigm I am attempting
**Trace** - lowest level, replacing comments with logs should default to this option so that logging options can easily avoid it.

Debug - do not use for commenting only code issues
**Info** - User story level commenting
**Warn** - used for TODOs
**Error** - use for FIXMEs
Fatal - do not use for commenting

The other problem is writing in a way that satisfies the comments "Why did we do this" and the log's "This is what is happening" as there is a past-tense present tense conflict. Without being overly verbose.

For example

```
"protected void setup() {
    log.trace("Loading hibernate session factory");
    final StandardServiceRegistry registry = new 
    StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
        .configure() // configures settings from hibernate.cfg.xml
        .build();
}"
```

the "log trace" replaces the need for a comment as it succinctly explains what setup is setting up

the comment remains because it is exposing the code semantics to the world such as which file is doing what.